Informative questions to ask in a faculty interview?
I have been in a number of faculty interviews where my overriding feeling was that we were judging how good the candidates were at being interviewed. This isn't necessarily useful information for the job they are being hired to do.
What questions are most informative to ask in an academic interview that will help provide useful information about the candidate as a potential faculty member?
Examples
These are questions I have seen that I don't think were useful in hindsight.

What is your approach to large class teaching?
Name some people at this university who are not in the department.
Why do you want to work here?
What skills would you bring?


I think the answers will be very subjective and your question is quite broad. It depends on several factors (university, country, department, field, etc.). Do you have any specific question in mind, that is, do you want to lead with a few examples, at least?

Are you required to ask the same questions of all candidates? If not, I would look at their CV and application materials. Presumably they've told you about what research they've done, what classes they've taught, and what service activities they've engaged in. I'd ask about anything that appears interesting or potentially valuable to your department.

I find the "name people not in the department" question thoroughly confusing.

I voted to reopen this. The current answer demonstrates that there are answers not based on opinions and I expect that more helpful answers are possible.

While getting my degree in psychometrics I learned a few things:
First, interviews are almost useless, but are slightly less useless if they are highly structured. People form an opinion in the first 15 seconds and then they unconsciously adjust the interview to match that. Also, many people think that they are the exception to this rule, but ... they aren't.
Second, one useful metric for many relatively high level jobs is the "in basket" test. Broadly, you assign the person tasks similar to what they would have to do on the job.
EDIT:  What might this look like? Well, to some extent, it depends on the school and department, but you could have the person give a class or, if that's too time consuming, have them teach something to the interviewers (with preparation). You can look at past research, of which there should be some, and you could ask them to, say, search the literature for a relevant paper, or design an experiment or study. And whatever else the person will have to do, if hired.

Could you give an example of an in basket test for a faculty job?

I added to my answer.
